# Question about ionic using "mousedown", "mousemove"

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to app creation and I have a question.

The following function will work in ionic in order to use it in a touch tablet, or "mousemove", "mousedown" it only works on pc with a mouse?

```
 document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
if(circlePointCollision(event.clientX,event.clientY,handle)){

    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",onmousemove);
    document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", onmouseup);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mouse Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) are the oldest and most widely supported user interaction events on the web, so yeah, they are supported by tablets and just about every device you will encounter.

There are also [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) created by Apple and a later event system called [Pointer Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) (pretty [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/pointer) at this point) that are meant to replace Mouse Events, but on devices that support these types of events, Mouse Events are still triggered for backward compatibility.